# UILabel content not refreshed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’m calling a json/rest service and passing the returned data to a UILabel on the screen. My screen is compounded by a static grouped table with many cells with title and detail. After setting  the uilabel.text with the returned content the screen doesn't show the value, but if I go and click on the UILabel the value is presented. It seems that I'm missing a command to refresh the screen. The code bellow is called from the viewDiDLoad method after receiving the data from the json/rest service in a call back block.

```
 [MEUser retrieveLoggedUserDetails:^(MEUser *meUser, NSError *error) {
        if (meUser) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.email.text = meUser.email;
                self.firstName.text = meUser.firstName;
                self.lastName.text = meUser.lastName;
                self.phone.text = meUser.phone;


            });
        }
    }];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Marcos

Comment: You have to call UIKit from the main thread **exclusively.** You fail to do it, thus your program invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: dispatch_get_main_queue() says that I'm invoking from the main thread, no?

Comment: Did you check whether self.firstname is nil or not?

Comment: Its not nil, the value firstname is passed to the object. I can assure that because after it when I click on the UILabel the content simple show up. It seems that when I click on the UIlabel it makes the whole thing refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Try this after setting the text.

```
[self.firstname setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Thats gonna throw an exception. You mean `[self.firstname setNeedsDisplay];`

Comment: @HermannKlecker Any reason why it will cause an exception? I am simply curious. The code within the block gets executed on main queue itself, though asynchronously. What is the cause of exception then?

Comment: I just assumed that self is a view controller, firstname is the UILabel and text is its `NSString` property representing the text to be displayed. If that is right then `NSString` will not respond to `setNeedsDisplay`. You can send that message to a view but not to a string.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thanks for the heads up, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies within your code itself. When you dispatch_async, the code within { } isn't executed quickly. Instead, your viewDidLoad will instantly return. Sometimes afterwards, the following line will hit:

```
self.firstname.text = meUser.firstname;
```

From what you describe, this is what I guess might be happening: When you click  (tap) the label, you are forcing the main queue to clear up its pending tasks, one of which maybe above code. So it puts the value into label, and displays it to you.

You need to decide when exactly do you want the label to refresh, and then only expect it to hold the updated text.

Comment: I didn't get your last thought "You need to decide when exactly do you want the label to refresh, and then only expect it to hold the updated text.""

Comment: I meant that code responsible for viewing the updated value ([self.firstname setNeedsDisplay]) should be called right after updating the value.

Comment: I've tried the command setNeedsDisplay after updating the value but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching the UILabel component to a UITextfield and mysteriously its working flawlessly.